# Problems with jquery .show() or .getElementById(). Not sure where the problem is or how to fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a choose your own adventure game (you may have seen my previous question about another issue I encountered). I finally got the home page to hide when the user presses space, but the next html element (the play page) won't show. I'm not sure if the issue lies in the initial `$("#play").show();` or in the code that prints the prompts and choices from the database object I have.

I asked for help on r/codinghelp, but only got a few responses that helped with the first part (pressing space originally did nada), but no help with the second. (see the reddit post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/comments/dr704b/press_space_to_start_function_not_working_for_a/)... you guys are a lot more responsive). I've been reading and re-reading the jquery docs, looking at w3schools and other resources to see if it was formatted incorrectly (my code seems 100% good to me). I've also run the debug function in FireFox developer edition and the one that comes with my text editor (Visual Studio Code).

First, my html:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="home">
    <p> [welcome text and whatever] </p>
  </div>
  <div id="play">
    <div id="prompt"></div>
    <div id="options"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the press space function:

```
window.onload = $("#play").hide();
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.key === " ") {
    $("#home").fadeOut(1000, function() { $("#play").show(10) });
  } false;
});
```

which seems fully functional at the moment. After that is the database, and then the code that prints the prompt and options:

```
var currentScene = 0;
window.printCurrentScene = function() {
  document.getElementById("prompt").innerHTML = "<div>" + this.database[currentScene].prompt;
  options = "";
  for (var i = 0, length = this.database[currentScene].options.length; i < length; i++) {
    options += "<p> <button onClick='setScene(" + this.database[currentScene].options[i].directTo + ")'>"
    + this.database[currentScene].options[i].content +
    "</button> </p>";
  }
  document.getElementById("options").innerHTML = options + "</div>";
}
window.setScene = function(num) {
  currentScene = num;
  window.printCurrentScene();
}
window.printCurrentScene();
```

Now, if this were working perfectly, the home page would fade out (it does), then the play page (scene 0) would show and print the scene (it doesn't), and the user would be able to select an option and move on to the scene it directs to ("directTo").

I got this error in vs code:
[image: error message]
and a similar one in Firefox, which I'm assuming means it can't read or access the div with id=prompt in my html. I don't quite understand what I need to rewrite so that it can access the "prompt" div, or if that's even what's causing the problem.

Sorry if any of this is unreadable, I'm a bit tired. Edits are very much welcome.

Comment: When is the window.printCurrentScene()  invoked ? is it invoked after the document is loaded. As we can see that error is only because the div element is not loaded in DOM.

Comment: Try using $(document).ready(function(){   }); to run scripts after the document is loaded in DOM.

Comment: @Narayanan that fixed it! thank you so much.